# How paginate results in Datatables properly (ajax, server-side)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have a datatable (https://www.datatables.net). I know how to retrieve data from a server and that's what I need. Since I need a server-side support for pagining via ajax, I wonder, how can I do that?

Here's how I can retrieve the 1st page:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  "ajax": '/ajax/get-data.json' 
});
```

I can retrieve other pages by making a request to '/ajax/get-data.json?page=XX'. My question is how to make the datatable do that? And in general, how to paginate results in Datatables using data from a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is server side processing

Basically set the datatable serverside parameter to true

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
     "ajax": '/data/handle' 
     "serverSide": true,
});
```

After that,whenever the table fires events on the server side you'll recieve via json the current page, the search and all related information. From that write a function that processes this data and returns the appropriate rows.

For more information see: https://datatables.net/manual/server-side.

Comment: but I don't see the parameter "page" on the server. what's it called?

Comment: and the same goes for "filter by" on the server, what is the parameter?

Comment: The start parameter for pagination and filter by should be added as a custom parameter in the ajax

Comment: Its called search in the sent parameters

Comment: do you mind taking a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813687/how-to-add-different-types-of-filters-in-datatable ?