# How to add different types of filters in DataTable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I want to add custom "filters" for a datatable. That is, in one column I want to add a dropdown, in another a datepicker, in another a textbox. My datatable receives data from a server.

How can I add those filters? **Preferably**, using a new contractor type which is `$(#example).DataTable`.

Comment: Have you read this? https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

Comment: @misha130, that's but I've seen it. Here's more specific question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821797/how-to-add-search-to-some-individual-columns-of-datatable-in-the-footer